# One time Feller continuity and n-time continuity functions in the context of Liggett

Tags: stochastic-processes, probability

In the book Continuous Time Markov Processes of T. Liggett in page 93 one reads:

[image]

Property 3.2 is given in the definition of Feller Processes in page 92:

[image]

I can't see how to conclude that 3.2 implies 3.4. For simplicity, let's try to prove that
$$x \mapsto  \Bbb{E}^x[f_1(x(t_1))f_2(x(t_2))] $$
 is continuous

I reasoned along the following lines, let $x_n \to x$

$$\Bbb{E}^{x_n}[f_1(x(t_1))f_2(x(t_2))] = \Bbb{E}^{x_n}[f_1(x(t_1))\Bbb{E}^{x_n}[f_2(x(t_2))\mid \mathcal{F}_{t_1}]] \\
 = \Bbb{E}^{x_n}[f_1(x(t_1))\Bbb{E}^{X(t_1)}[f_2(x(t_2- t_1)]] = \Bbb{E}^{x_n}[h_1(x(t_1))] \to \Bbb{E}^{x}[h_1(x(t_1))] = \Bbb{E}^{x}[f_1(x(t_1))f_2(x(t_2))]$$

This would prove the result if it wasn't for the fact that I used property 3.3 at the step:

$$\Bbb{E}^{x_n}[f_1(x(t_1))\Bbb{E}^{x_n}[f_2(x(t_2))\mid \mathcal{F}_{t_1}]]   = \Bbb{E}^{x_n}[f_1(x(t_1))\Bbb{E}^{X(t_1)}[f_2(x(t_2- t_1)]] $$

I tried to prove that

$$ \Bbb{E}^{x_n}[f_2(x(t_2))\mid \mathcal{F}_{t_1}] \to \Bbb{E}^{x}[f_2(x(t_2))\mid \mathcal{F}_{t_1}]$$
But I couldn't

Is there a way to prove this result without using (weak) Markov Property?

It seems to me that there isn't, but the author makes us  believe 3.4 should follow only from 3.2

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Use the simple Markov property to write ${\Bbb E}^x[f_1(x(t_1))f_2(x(t_2))]$ as ${\Bbb E}^x[f_1(x(t_1))g(x(t_1))]$ where $g(y) ={\Bbb E}^y[f_2(x(t_2-t_1))]$. Notice that $g\in C(S)$ because of (3.2), hence the product $f_1g$ is also an element of $C(S)$.

Comment: Thank you John for your answer. I would like however to know if there is a proof that doesn't use the simple Markov Property.

Comment: There can be no such proof, as the simple Markov property is needed to express the joint distribution of the process at two times to (3.2), which concerns the distribution of the process at a single time.  I agree that Liggett's wording is unclear.  What he no doubt intends is to show that for a simple Markov process (as at the beginning of Chapter 2) the "Feller property" (3.2) implies an analogous property for the joint distributions (3.4).

Comment: your comment should be your answer.